# Why my quarkus/hibernate rest API unable to acuire JDBC connection?

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus

The application lunches correctly, i am trying to consume a login API, when i lunch login process using swagger-ui, an exception is triggered:

> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Erreur d'E/S: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

> 2022-11-15 14:03:18,857 WARN  (Agroal_2230584771) Datasource 'default': Erreur d'E/S: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

this is the url from the database propreties panel: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@bodswv092:1521:DEMO`

How can i resolve this problem ?

Comment: Is the `Datasource 'default'` really the correct one?

Comment: This seems to be a network issue ?

Comment: problem solved, i was using the wrong data source configuration.

Comment: So `default` was wrong? Surprise ^^

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong datasource configuration, when i put the right host, credentials and service name in the application.propreties file.